# Jquery Scroll Event Doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm looking to make a div appear when a page is scrolled down. The thing is that my page body has overflow hidden as well as most of other divs except the table that appears at some point on the page when the button is pressed. So that table has overflow:scroll as needed and I try to hook that scroll event on it. But it doesn't work anyway. What can it be?

Here is my html:

```
<body>  
  <div class="maine">
<table id="tableToClone" class="ts">
  <div class="backtotopplank"></div>
                    </table>  
  </div>   
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
  background:black;
  width:100%;
}

.ts  {  
  background:red;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
  margin:auto auto;
    width:70%;
  height:3000px;
    overflow:scroll;
}


.maine{
  width:70%;
  margin:auto auto;
  background:white; 
  position:relative;
    overflow-x:hidden;  
}

.backtotopplank{
    background:black;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    position:fixed;
    width:153px;
    height:56px;
    left:900px;
    bottom:0px;
    cursor: pointer;
display:none;
}
```

And JQuery:

```
$(".ts").scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 400) {
    $(".backtotopplank").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(".backtotopplank").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Comment: I check code and come to find that its window that scrolling not table with class 'ts'. Try window instead of the class 'ts'. 

Try $(window).scroll instead of $('.ts').scroll

Comment: A problem is that on my page I tried both window and document and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please check I just added an answer for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 100) {
     $(".backtotopplank").fadeIn();
    } else {
     $(".backtotopplank").fadeOut();
   }
  });
});
```

Try this It might Help you. It work for me.

Comment: Man you are amazing, it was that simple, just including document ready! Thank you so much!